# Jsoup Not Parsing Particluar DIv

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I am unable to get the div `'live ticker'` from [here](https://webapp.onefootball.com/en/match/real-madrid-vs-liverpool-5-718129?period=FullTime&variable=g4) using Jsoup Library.

Here is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Link).get();

Element link = doc.select("div.data-of-match-live-experience").first();
Elements squad = doc.select("div.data-of-match-live-experience");
Elements li = squad.select("li"); // select all li from ul

Log.d("jsoup", "size: " + li.size());
```

Comment: You saw the tag in the inspect element which is generated by javascript and trying to parse it with Jsoup? It cannot be done. For this you will need a headless browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text in this tag in not part of initial html, but is set by JavaScript after page is loaded. You can check it by disabling JavaScript in your browser. Jsoup only gets static html, does not execute JavaScript code.

When you examine what connections are made from the page you will find out that the value is updated through request to this API:

https://shapeshifter-api.onefootball.com/v1/en/match/live-experience/5/6700/718129

Make a request to this url, parser result and you will get desired value.

Comment: Thats great @Luk, How did you get the link ? Assuming we are in a middle of live match. How would i be able to parse real time data then? Please guide.

Comment: You can use for example https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference to track what connections are made. Other browsers should have something similar. Check what requests are send during live match and which of them returns data you are looking for.